# How can I adjust the front derailleur range of my bike?

Tags: shifting, derailleur-front

My front derailleur is kinda old and malfunctioning and while I'm not buying a new, I would like to make it shift only from the small cog to the middle one. It's, currently, shifting from the biggest cog to the middle one (it doesn't make it through the three anymore). How can I make this little adjustment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is really too broad to be easily answered. Please go through this guide and edit question if you still have problems. https://www.parktool.com/en-int/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment

Comment: Maybe you simply have too much friction in the cable (or too much tension) which prevents it from going to the smallest chainring?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is that you only want the chain to shift  between the larger and the middle of   3 chainwheels (or what some call sprockets) .

You can do this easily by adjusting the limit screws, which you should normally find close together on the derailleur. One screw prevents the derailleur from guiding the chain too high, and the other limits its movement in the opposite direction.  Most manufacturers  label the screws  with an "L" for the  low gear   or "H" for high gear.

With the bike upside down or on a stand, you should be able to screw the L screw far enough in so that you can only shift between the higher two gears.

See help pages such as  https://www.parktool.com/en-int/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment  and  https://sheldonbrown.com/front-derailers.html  for more instruction.

Image of Shimano 600 front derailleur (1980)

[image: Shimano 600 front derailleur (1980)]